# Javascript code, unterminated string literal with included javascript

Tags: php, javascript, string, include, literals

This script works fine, unless the included file contains javascript, then it breaks with the "unterminated string" literal error. Removing spaces and linebreaks does not cure the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myArray = [
'url',
'url2',
'url3',
'url4',
'url5',
];
var i, numDomains = myArray.length, found = false;
for (i = 0; i < numDomains; i++) {
if (document.referrer.indexOf(myArray[i]) > -1) {
found = true;
}
}
document.write((found ? '<?php include("file1.php"); ?>' : '<?php include("file2.php"); ?>'));
</script>
```

A good solution would be where the included file can be any normal html file.

This is the output of the offending file:

```
<!-- google_ad_client = "pub-0705348955426556";/* ORG 468x60 */ google_ad_slot =     "2106718798";google_ad_width = 468;google_ad_height = 60;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script><script src="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/test_domain.js"></scri
```

Comment: Just a note - You've got an extra comma after 'url5'

Comment: @Marko, I believe that is actually allowed, at least in some browsers. It can make things easier sometimes.

Comment: @MatrixFrog IE will barf on it

Comment: Post the output of `file1.php` and `file2.php`

Comment: The site would not permit me to use "unterminated string literal" as a tag.  This is curious as it appears in nearly 50 posts

Comment: @Marko - is the last comma redundant?

Comment: Is there any chance to use file_get_contents() instead of include() ? Sometimes the included files doesn't really need to be evaluated. So you could easily escape the content with addslashes

Comment: @ w35l3y
Just tried 
    <?php file_get_contents(file2.htm"); ?>
 but the output is null - like ''

Answer (score 3):

If `file1.php` or `file2.php` output anything with un-escaped `'` characters or line breaks, this would cause the message you're getting.

Try removing all line breaks from the offending file, its output looks like this:

```
 <!-- google_ad_client = "pub-0705348955426556";/* ORG 468x60 */ google_ad_slot = "2106718798";google_ad_width = 468;google_ad_height = 60; --><script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script<script src="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/test_domain.js">
```

Comment: include() does not return the evaluated code of the file, so addslashes is out of question. unless you are talking about using it with output control functions ob_*()

Answer (score 1):

Remove last comma from this line:

```
var myArray = [ 'url', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url5', ];
/*                                                   ^ */
```

Comment: Thanks for cutting my lunch. Just kidding :) I didn't post my comment as an answer since he mentions that when the .php file contains javascript, THAT's when the script breaks.. so I figured it's not related to the array.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it still breaks, even with the redundant comma removed.

Answer (score 0):

If there are line breaks in the include files, that causes error. For example:

```
var a = "abc
adada"; // may cause error
```